# How to detect SSL Policy errors with .net?

Tags: c#, ssl

I'm totally new to handling policy errors when making web requests so I'm a little bit confused at this point..

I have this task to call a web service but not allow the call to be made if the server I'm calling has an invalid certificate.

So I created a method to call a site with invalid cerificate and using ServerCertificateValidationCallback to prevent the call to be made if the certificate is invalid.

What I need is a quick walkthrough in how to detect the invalid certificate inside my handler. I would have thought that the call to "revoked.badssl.com" would have caused something in the sslPolicyErrors object to be something other than "none" but is this not the case? I see no difference at this point in calling badssl or my other url that has a valid certificate.

For example: if https://pinning-test.badssl.com/ is opened in chrome it shows a "ERR_SSL_PINNED_KEY_NOT_IN_CERT_CHAIN" (although IE shows the page). How do I find this information that chrome deems as an invalid certificate so I can, if I want to, also handle it as invalid in my code??

This is my code I'm trying with at the moment:

```
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (sender, cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors) =>
    {
      if(someError?!)
        return false;

      return true;
    };

    using (HttpClient client = DefaultHttpClient())
    {
      Uri uri = new Uri("https://revoked.badssl.com/");
      string jsonObj = "{}";
      var content = new StringContent(jsonObj, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
      HttpResponseMessage response = client.PostAsync(uri, content).Result;
    }
```

Comment: By using `return true` in `ServerCertificateValidationCallback` you are explicitly saying "I don't care at all about any certificate". What made you think you had to even add another callback?

Comment: Yes, I should change my example code. What I have done so far is to only add a breakpoint on the "return true" so far just to check the values of the four parameters sender, cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors to see what they contain. But since I unecpectedly never get anything else but "none" as value for sslPolicyErrors I haven't really understood how to implement some decent code to prevent the call.. I added some code to clarify now..

Comment: Well, does the certificate contain any [of the errors that enum handles](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms145055%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)? It doesn't seem like so

Comment: I agree, it seems as if that is the case which I thought/think is strange but since I'm totally noob at this I can't tell if that's "ok" or if I can use any other way to detect the revoked certificate.

Answer (score 0):

By default the revocation check is not performed. You need to set it on the [ServicePointManger Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.servicepointmanager.aspx) for your application to check it.

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.CheckCertificateRevocationList = true;
```